# serverless - node.js crypto package is not working

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless

Trying to generate RSA keys with `crypto` package and deploy it on AWS Lambda, I get an error that `crypto` package is `undefined`. Are there easy ways to deploy this package to Lambda without having building docker containers?

Yes, I read that node.js native packages have different binaries on mac (my current os) and linux, so there is an approach to build docker and deploy it, but I found it's not very clear for me, so if this is the only way to do it, maybe there are good resources to read about it also.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a thought, but could it be that you are using an old Node version in your Lambda function where the crypto package wasn't yet included? I believe it is a pretty recent development. Maybe 2017. See if you can run a newer Node version using serverless.

Comment: @Imre_G Actually, aws lambda supports 8.10 node version, and actually crypto package available for this node version , as I found there are no generateKeyPair function, but at least crypto instance should not be `undefined`, what I got

Comment: @Horhi the original comment is right. it does not matter what you read in the documentation: if you do actually deploy a lambda and try to use crypto, it will just fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to avoid docker as well but it's actually pretty easy to setup. Install the [Community Edition](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-engine)

Pull [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda/) with this:

```
docker pull lambci/lambda
```

To mount your dev folder run this:

```
docker run -v ~/[mydev-folder]:/var/task  lambci/lambda:nodejs8.10
```

Open Kitematic from the Docker app. You should see the container you pulled. Select it and start it if it's not started. Then click "Exec" and you should get a bash prompt opened in /var/task which should be pointing at your dev folder.

I usually delete node_modules and then run `npm install` from inside the docker container. I also `sls deploy` from there was well.

Comment: Please note that this is not the correct answer. crypto is defined in AWS Lambda -- just not on the global object. If you are reading this, please look at my answer for the right solution. Tagging @Horhi to change the selected answer to the right onw

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the package as `require("crypto")`. It is just not defined on the global object.

```js
const handler = () => {
  console.log(crypto); // undefined
  console.log(global.crypto); // undefined
  console.log(require("crypto"); // Bingo! :D
}
```

---

If you arrived here because you are bundling a Nodejs lambda with rollup and using a version of `uuid` 7+, then you need to add

```
external: ["crypto"]
```

to your `rollup.config.js` so that rollup does not attempt to replace the `require` statement by whatever if finds better.